# Async.times runs parallely or not?

Tags: node.js

I basically wants to run a batch process parallely in node.js. I read the documentation but was not able to come to conclusion. Can someone explain it or any other way to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes .times executes the functions in parallel.
Basically the doc says that .times works as .map, and .map docs say:

> Note, that since this function applies the iteratee to each item in
>   parallel, there is no guarantee that the iteratee functions will
>   complete in order.

Also here's how you can check it.
I run 5 async functions each of those takes 1s. But the .times finishes in 1,004 seconds (not 5 seconds)

```js
const async = require('async');

let asyncFn = function (callback) {
 setTimeout(function () {
  callback(null);
 }, 1000);
};

console.time();
async.times(5, (n, next) => asyncFn(next), () => console.timeEnd()); //the output was 1004 ms
```

The other way would probably be to use .parallel which obviously runs the functions in parallel.